# How to disable a CheckBox column in a DBGrid

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

How to disable or readonly a checkbox column in a DBGrid. I'm using wwDbGrid and EditControl option.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the component but did you try something like:

```
wwDBGrid.Columns[1].ReadOnly:=True;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set as readonly the TField that is binded with the checkbox column

You can do it through the Grid component

```
TwwDBGrid(Sender).ColumnByName(FieldName).ReadOnly := True;
```

or through the dataset's TField

```
TField.ReadOnly := True;
```